# calculating in excel based on criteria from different columns

Tags: excel, calculated-columns

I have been looking at different forums and I hope someone could help me here. 
I want to conditionally format a cell based on certain criteria
[The below would be a master table from which I will need to select data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IddIA.png)

[and compute the values in this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE9f6.png)

So, in the formula, I want to see how Phil's time is allocated across three Sprints. So, I will need to look at Sprint column in table 1 and search for Sprint 1, find Phil assigned to Sprint 1 and add the "estimate" total in table 2.

I saw something like this on the forum, but, no luck. I also tried using lookups and index and all I see are errors. If you have an easy way of solving for this, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMIFS`

The formula in B2 is:

```
=SUMIFS($I:$I,$J:$J,$A2,$G:$G,B$1)
```

[image: Sprint Screenshot]

Comment: Thank You! I will try this one out and let you know. Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as your chosen answer so the question can be finalized.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a pretty basic sumifs.

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[estimate], Table1[sprint], H$2, Table1[assignee], $G3)
```

Don't drag the formula to fill the other cells. Copy and paste into the larger area. Dragging will shift the column references like relative cell addressing. Copying and pasting will treat the structured table references as absolute.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! I will try this one out. The SUMIFS did not occur in my mind at all.